# How can we make an external call without an ongoing transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jdbc, jboss

We're using Spring & Hibernate in JBoss 4.2.3 and are calling an external system, which could take a while, as part of processing requests. To eliminate long-lived database locks we're not writing to our database until after the external call has returned.
But Hibernate does not like being without a transaction so we have a read-only transaction, started by Spring, until we're doing our writes (in a new read-write subtransaction). Unfortunately this still means we're retaining resources during the external call, the allocated connection from the pool.
Is there a way to make the external call without an ongoing transaction when the rest of the execution (before and after) needs one?
Is there a better way of deferring the actual transaction until we really need it and still keep Hibernate happy?

Comment: Does the request have to wait for the external call to finish?  Or can the external call plus database write happen asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, we need to hit our database to find out if the external call is required and also for the configuration (e.g. URL) for the call. We also need the response to write into our local database before we can return to our caller.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to call the external system in your persistence layer? It seems more logical to do this kind of thing outside, before you hit persistence.

Comment: The call itself is not from our persistence layer, but things need to be read in layers above the external call and we want to use lazy loading for some of those things (and that's when Hibernate gets picky about transactions/sessions).

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a transaction for reads.

Here is an example where the read call goes straight to the DAO object, but the write call is done within a transaction (using Spring's TransactionTemplate helper object):

```
public ContainerType getContainerType(Long id) {
    return this.containerTypeDao.getContainerType(id);
}

public Long saveContainerType(final ContainerType containerType) {
    return (Long) this.transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {

        public Long doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            try {
                return containerTypeDao.saveContainerType(containerType);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                status.setRollbackOnly();
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```